# How can I clear just enabled fields from FormPanel?

Tags: gxt

I have a form panel (GXT from Sencha) with 3 fields. One of them is disabled. I want to implement clear button which will clear just enabled fields and will leave the value of disabled field. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you checked out `public boolean isEnabled()`

Comment: Yeap, I tried 
 List<Field<?>> fields = formPanel.getFields();
        for (Field field :fields){
            if (field.isEnabled()){
                field.clear();
            }
        }
But I though that there is a more generic way.